# creek 4040s2 (amp)

Tags: amplifier, audio, potentiometer, repair

I have a 4040 s2 amplifier. The 10kOhms balance potentiometer seems to be broken (it used to makes a crackling noise when fiddle with).
Being quarantined, the only repair that seems currently possible is to short the corresponding pins where the potentiometer used to be. 
My question though: is there is a nominal/residual resistance when the potentiometer is in the middle (or neutral position)? I have resistors that i can use instead of just shorting the pins

I'd gladly check that with my multimeter but it is broken... and I'm quarantined.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

An audio balance circuit typically looks like this:

[image]

(borrowed from Neil_UK's answer to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/288710/audio-balance-control))

The potmeter needs to be a **linear** model meaning that when is at the middle position the resistance is divided 50/50. So for a 10 k potmeter that means 5 kohm on each side.

I would simply just **remove** the balance potmeter or just disconnect it from the left and right channels. The audio might be attenuated less that way (so it gets louder) but you can simply lower the volume to compensate for that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just shorted each channel's input and output together and the crackling noise is gone... But I have no trebles. Can I apply the same reasoning to the treble and bass potentiometers as well ?